# Could I have been banned on Stack Overflow without noticing it?

Tags: support

I don't know why, but recently it seems like I don't have any interaction with other users.

I reply to questions and no one even considers them, 0 upvotes, 0 downvotes and no comments. This isn't usual to me, usually I always get comments, votes, etc...

I've heard of a type of ban that the user can answer to the questions, but the other people don't see his answers.

Can this happen on Stack Overflow? And if yes, how to see if I'm banned or not?

Comment: I've just commented on what appears to be your latest answer. I don't think you're hell-banned.

Comment: Fairly sure there's no silent banning on Stack Overflow, you're last answer was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499385/how-can-i-force-nstextfield-to-only-allow-numbers/13499976#13499976)?

Comment: I see the comment, thanks.

Comment: It's called [hellbanning](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html)

Comment: I see... banned people

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Stack Overflow doesn't have [slow/hell bans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellbanning). If you were suspended you would have received an email from a moderator and your reputation would be locked at 1, and if you were banned from posting questions or answers (or both), you would get a message when you tried to post.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but are you sure Jeff did not checked that feature in late at night when nobody was looking? Just in case?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If he did, he seriously screwed up the algorithm, given the crap that makes it through all the time...

Comment: That gives me an idea... we could at least implement this for reviews. Let the drones upvote crap all they want, but without any effect on the site itself. That would be fun.

Comment: +1 for the word hellbanning. I didn't know that word.